# read int array of unknown length from file

Tags: c++, arrays, file

How to read an array of integers with unknown length from a file?
I don't see a way to get the size of the array, so I tried some temporary-string-stuff,
but my code explodes...

any better ideas?

Comment: try using `std::vector<std::string>` or `std::vector<int>`

Comment: @GuySirton, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: @GuySirton: That's absolutely terrible advice. `eof` is just almost never correct.

Comment: @KerrekSB: It's pseudo-code, as is continue doing this until you run out of data.  I see your point how this can be wrong/confusing, the point was just to illustrate keep reading and push into a vector while you have something to read (yes the actual code would differ).

Comment: As an aside, if the file consists _only_ of integers and you want all of them, you can get the number by getting the file size and dividing by `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @Useless Only if the size of an integer in the file is the same as the size of one in your machine.  They usually aren't.  And of course, there's also no reliable method of getting the file size either.

Comment: @chris It's interesting that in the article you site, the top answers are wrong.  You shouldn't use `eof()`, because it is unreliable.  It may be set before the input fails, or not, depending on the input you're doing.

Answer (score 8):

Use `std::vector`:

```
std::ifstream inFile(fileName);

std::vector<int> ints{
    std::istream_iterator<int>(inFile),
    std::istream_iterator<int>()
};
```

`std::vector` provides dynamic storage, so it resizes as needed to fit what it holds. All I do is utilize the constructor that takes a pair of iterators and loops through them, beginning to end, and copies the values into the vector. The iterators I'm using will read integers from the file until one can't, as is the case when the end of file is reached. I also use uniform initialization to avoid the most vexing parse, an easy mistake to make when using this form of the constructor.

Comment: This suffers from the most vexing parse.  `ints` is a function declaration.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Oops, one second.

Comment: Personally, I've always found this more readable, and less typing: `std::istream_iterator<int> in_begin(inFile), in_end; std::vector<int> ints(in_begin, in_end);`

Comment: C++03 MVP elimination: add extra parens around first argument: `std::vector<int> ints((std::istream_iterator<int>(infile)), std::istream_iterator<int>());`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, Yeah, that's another option, and it *is* less typing and does avoid running into MVP. And Jerry, Thanks for the C++03 input.   That extra set does indeed remove the ambiguity, and is probably the easiest way while retaining the same code structure, as opposed to declaring something beforehand.

Comment: And `std::ifstream inFile(...);` is also a function declaration. </nitpick> :)

Comment: @jrok, I appreciate the free laughs, thanks :) Just for you, I made the file stream object declaration valid for use with the vector, assuming `fileName` is declared and is of the right type.

Comment: @JerryCoffin According to the standard, extra parens around any argument will do the trick.  At least one compiler blew it, however, if they weren't around the first.  (I generally put them around all of the arguments, just for orthogonality.)