# Garbage value when putting values from a text file into dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I'm having an issue with my dynamic array. I'm trying to input the values that are into a text file into a dynamic array of length where size is the size of my text file.

For some reason I'm getting -842150451 repeated, idk if its something simple as not properly intializing it or maybe im using a << in the wrong way.

*PS: I tried debugging and even if I print out the individual index, I still get that value.*

***My code:***

```
    cout << "\nEnter a command and file ";
    getline(cin, line);
    command = line.substr(0, line.find(" "));
    names = line.substr(line.find(" ")+1);
    ifstream readText;
    readText.open(names += ".txt");
    int size;
    readText >> size;
    int *someArray = new int[size];
    
    
    if (command == ("Start"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            readText >> someArray[i];

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << someArray[i] << endl;
        }
        
    }

    else if (command == "do this")
    {
            
        //used to test to see if it works
        cout << someArray[0] << endl;
        cout << someArray[1] << endl;
        cout << someArray[2] << endl;
     }
```

**the contents are just values like**

> 94032
>
> 233332
>
> 2121
>
> 112
>
> 423424

Comment: This code is correct as long as it fits the contents  of your input stream. Please provide a [mcve] including the input that reproduces the problem.

Comment: i just provided the lines of code that i used for the input thank you for taking the time to look at my problem

Comment: Better, but especially the contents of the file you read would be interesting.

Comment: And you should check whether or not the file was opened successfully and the input operations succeeded.

Comment: the values are just plain numbers like 94032 233332 2121 112 423424 except they each have their own line,

Comment: when the user enters Start and the name of the file the contents of the file are shown properly

Comment: Alright, so the first number you read is used as the size of your array and to determine the length of the input. As your code stands right now, it will attempt to read 94032 integers, and the file must contain at least that many after the initial integer. Is that the case? If not, add a new line containing the number of integers you want to read to the very beginning of the input file.

Comment: ahh i see, and the first value is 397 and the number of elements i need to print is 397

Comment: somethign i noticed is that when i print out the values of the text file the first value is not printed out, but i belive like you said it uses that first value as the size of the text file

Comment: IMPORTANT note: initialize `int size` to 0, unless you can point to a spec which says that the `>>` operator will always set a value, even if it doesn't find a number (otherwise, you'll create an array with a garbage-value size if there was no number at the beginning of the stream)

Comment: Well of course it does, you consume the first integer from the file with `readText >> size;` and save it in `size`. So the first integer needs to be exactly one less then the total number of integers in the file.

Comment: iAdjunct thank you for your feedback i set the size = 0 to, but it returns other garbage values although not the same repeated value

Comment: Try `memset ( someArray , 0 , sizeof(someArray) )` post-`new` and see if that changes anything.

Comment: Btw, -842150451 is cdcdcd in hex, I believe that MSCV uses something like that to indicate uninitialized memory in debug mode. And if you only want to get the job done, have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162293/read-int-array-of-unknown-length-from-file).

Comment: int *someArray = new int[size];
memset(someArray, 0, sizeof(someArray));

Comment: and the first index is 0 followed by garbage values

Comment: @iAdjunct That line is wrong, `sizeof(someArray) == sizeof(void*)`. Also, using `memset` in C++ is stupid, use `std::fill` instead. And `new int[size]` is not really better and should be `std::vector<int>(size)` instead.

Comment: @BaummitAugen - Right, forgot he defined it that way. And no, it's not [always] stupid - memset can have performance benefits when all you want to do is zero out an array.

Comment: @iAdjunct I do not believe that without prove. It would be easy for the implementation to detect when it is dealing with POD / trivially copyable  types and pointers. I would be *very* surprised if any of the big implementations would not optimize this with `memset` behind the scenes. Heck, compilers have been optimizing entire loops to `memset` for years, even without any template magic.

Comment: i tried it with vector implementation and prints out garbage values , hmm the only other thing i can think of is that i am using an else if statement and printing out the values of the first 3 index and coming out with garbage values